# Replace all periods with hyphens recursively

Tags: bash, shell-script, rename

To replace all spaces with hyphens, in all files/folders, in all sub-directories, I run the following:

```
find /path/to/folder -depth -name "* *" -execdir rename 's/ /-/g' "{}" \;
```

And it works.

To replace all periods (excluding extensions) with hyphens, in all files/folders, in all sub-directories, I run the following:

```
find /path/to/folder -depth -name "*.*" -execdir rename 's/./-/g' "{}" \;
```

And it doesn't work. Instead it turns filenames into one long ------------

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Beware dots are also used in filenames to hide files when dot is the first character or to give a hint as to the format of the data stored within (generally called extensions). For instance a `my.file.tar.gz.gpg` would indicate a gpg-encrypted, gzip-compressed `tar` archive. Replacing those with `-` would unhide the files and confuse software which rely o the `.format` naming convention

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A period is special in regular expressions, it matches any character. To match a period literally, backslash it:

```
rename 's/\./-/g'
```

With `-execdir` with some `find` implementations including GNU `find`, every name will start with a period. To skip the period, use

```
's/(?<=.)\./-/g'
```

`(?<=.)` is a *look-behind assertion* that checks there is something before the period, but it doesn't get replaced.

Some perl `rename` variant also support a `-d` option which makes so that the code only acts on the basename of the file and then you don't even need the non-standard `-execdir`¹:

```
find /path/to/folder -depth -name '* *' -exec rename -d 's/\./-/g' {} +
```

If you want to keep the last dot, you can use a *look-ahead assertion* to only replace dots that are followed by a dot somewhere.

```
's/(?<=.)\.(?=.*\.)/-/g'
```

---

<sup>¹ That means you can also use `+` instead of `;` to call one `rename` to handle many files. Some `find` implementations also support `+` for `-execdir` but would still need to run `rename` at least once for each directory containing files with `-` in their name.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, so I now have:

find /path/to/folder -depth -name "*.*" -execdir rename 's/\./-/g' "{}" \;

but it returns "Can't rename ./234.234.234 -/234-234-234: No such file or directory"
where 234.234.234 is a .txt file

Comment: Oh, it replaces the starting dot :-) Check the update.

Comment: Is very good now, though two problems still remain:
1) Also changes the extension. So .txt now becomes -txt
2) Changes the dot at the beginning of hidden files, so ._hidden.ext becomes -_hidden-ext

Comment: In a unix filename, there's no _formal_ concept of "extension" -- it's just characters in the filename.

Comment: @ItHertz Check the update.

Comment: Thanks again for your help! Those issues are solved. Still two problems remain. 1) Folders don't have extensions, so should not retain the last dot. Perhaps the answer is to run two lines, one for folders only and one for files only. However, for me this is fringe, as I'm not sure I have any folders with dots in the name but for testing. 2) Files with two dots in their extension (.ext.xmp) only retain the last dot (-ext.xmp). I'm going to guess this is a problem without a neat solution.

Comment: @ItHertz: If you can define "extension" in a way a computer can recognise it, it should be possible to implement a solution.

Comment: Another way to match a dot is with a character class: `[.]`. I prefer this way, because it works unchanged if the regex string gets evaluated by shells etc. (unlike backslashes, which need to be doubled for each layer of evaluation).